# Request header field Access-Control-Request-Methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to send a POST request from my website to my remote server but I encounter some CORS issues.

I searched in the internet but didn't find a solution to my specific problem. 
This is my ajax request params:

```
var params = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Request-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Request-Methods': 'POST'
    }
```

On the backend side in this is my code in python:

```
@app.route(SETTINGS_NAMESPACE + '/<string:product_name>', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@graphs.time_method()

def get_settings(product_name):
    settings_data = helper.param_validate_and_extract(request, None, required=True, type=dict, post_data=True)
    settings_data = json.dumps(settings_data)
    response = self._get_settings(product_name, settings_data)
    return output_json(response, requests.codes.ok, headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
    })
```

I get an error on my console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [http://path-to-my-server]. Request header field
>   Access-Control-Request-Methods is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

I did notice that I can add also `'Access-Control-Request-Headers'` but I wasn't sure if it necessary and it cause me more problems so I removed it.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your ajax request shouldn't send `Access-Control` headers, only the server sends those headers.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. post it as an answer and i'll approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request shouldn't send `Access-Control` headers, only the server sends those headers to allow the servers to describe the set of origins that are permitted to read that information using a web browser.

The same-origin policy generally doesn't apply outside browsers, so the server has to send CORS headers or JSONP data if the browser is going to be able to get the data.

The browser doesn't send those headers to the server, it doesn't have to, it's the server that decides whether or not the data is available to a specific origin.

Remove the `header` option from the `params` object, and it should work